# Child observable having no effect when called using tap operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm relatively new to RxJS so I'm trying to get a better grasp on how Observables work when they're chained together using operators. I can manage to get them working properly by chaining them using subscribe, but that's bad practice.

The code below is being used in an Angular application that involves displaying a form to the user that allows them to view and save settings for the application. The form first makes a GET request to an API to receive the saved settings represented in JSON format. Once this is returned the settings are displayed to the user. The user can then modify the settings and save them when happy.

The issue is that for some reason the final observable, the one inside the `setSettings` function does not seem to be working correctly. From my console logs I can see that the function is being called by the observable inside `buildSettingsForm`, however the commands inside the tap operator seem to be doing nothing.

The call to `console.log(val)` is never executed, but I know that the call to `this.getSettingsFromSerial$` is definitely being called as I can see the logs for that. Therefore it seems like when the call to tap is executed something happens and none of the inner commands are actually being executed. This would make sense as the calls to `this.addRange` inside the for loop aren't being called either, which means my form is being left empty.

```
initSettings(){
    if(this.savedSettingsState !== undefined)
    {
        if(this.unsavedSettingsExist())
        {
          console.log("Unsaved settings exist");
          this.openUnsavedSettingsModal();
          return;
        }
    }

    this.getOrganisations$().pipe(
        exhaustMap((res: AdminOrganisation[]) => {
          this.organisations = res;
          this.currentOrganisationSerial = this.organisations[0].serialRef;
          this.currentOrganisationName = this.organisations[0].serialName;
          return this.buildSettingsForm(this.currentOrganisationSerial);
        })
    ).subscribe();
}

buildSettingsForm(serial: string) {
    this.ipRangeFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          ipRanges: this.formBuilder.array([])
        }
    );

    this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;

    return merge(
        this.ipRangeFormArray.valueChanges.pipe(
            tap(_ => {
              this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;
              console.log("numArrayElements: " + this.numArrayElements)
            })
        ),
        this.setSettings(serial)
    );
}

setSettings(serial: string) {
    console.log("setSettings");
    return this.getSettingsFromSerial$(serial).pipe(
        tap(val => {
          console.log("val");
          console.log(val);
          this.savedSettingsState = val;
          this.ipRestrictionEnabled = val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRestrictionEnabled;
          for (const i of val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRanges) {
            this.addRange(i.startRange, i.endRange, i.label);
          }
          this.displayForm = true;
        })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Looks like getSettingsFromSerial$ isn’t emitting

Comment: @bryan60 Should I be subscribing directly to it? I thought the whole point is to merge the observables into one and then subscribe to that? The observable is subscribed to inside initSettings though.

Comment: @bryan60 How do I get it to emit?

Comment: Missed that originally as this stream is a bit confusing to follow. Looks like the getSettingsFromSerial$ function isn’t emitting. What happens in that function?

Comment: @bryan60 It's just simply returning the Observable from a GET produces by a service. It's only a single line.

Comment: Do you see the http request getting executed?

Comment: @bryan60 It's definitely being executed yeah.

Comment: With a 200 response? Dunno, think I’d need to see that function and it’s service call. Something is blocking that from getting through to tap. Usually an error of some kind. Maybe build a blitz

Comment: @bryan60 I've just had another look and the behaviour is weird. So when the page is loaded initially both requests are sent and received as intended. However when I attempt to swap to a different set of settings the requests are not sent at all. Could it be something to do with the exhaustMap used inside InitSettings or another operator? I feel like the subscription is ending somewhere where it shouldn't.

Comment: Try using switchMap instead of exhaustMap...8 haven’t used exhaustMap in the wild but it’s supposed to ignore emissions from the outter till inner completes.

Comment: @bryan60 Just tried, it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Idk then, gotta make a blitz or something cause from what I see here. Everything looks fine. Things terminating unexpectedly though reeks of unhandled or silently swallowed error

Comment: I find it *much* easier to work with the streams in a more declarative (less procedural) manner. See the code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS/tree/master/APM-Final

Answer (score 0):

I worked up a blitz which shows that there isn't any issue in the code here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9x1js?file=src/app/app.component.ts

the issue is somewhere else in your pipeline causing an unhandled or swallowed exception, probably in whatever `getSettingsFromSerial$` is doing.  adding an error handler to your subscribe and logging it might help figure out what is going on. I've also seen similar mysterious issues when someone has an interceptor swallowing all their http errors that they forgot about.